# Multiple file-upload Symfony 3.2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony-3.1

I'm wondering about to handle the multiple file upload in SF3. Indeed, in previous version you had to declare one field with a doctrine one-to-many relationship on entity. 
example :

```
namespace ProjectBundle\Entity;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjectBundle\Entity\SliderImage", mappedBy="project",orphanRemoval= true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $sliderImages;
```

and in the reversed entity :

```
namespace ProjectBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PlatformBundle\Entity\Image;

/**
 * SliderImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="slider_image")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ProjectBundle\Repository\SliderImageRepository")
 */
class SliderImage extends Image {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProjectBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="sliderImages")
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $project;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    protected function getUploadDir() {
        return 'uploads/images/projects/sliders';
    }

    function getProject() {
        return $this->project;
    }

    function setProject(Project $project) {
        $this->project = $project;
    }

}
```

and finally, in the FormType you just had to add this field and manage in JavaScript in Twig side:

> ```
>         ->add('sliderImages', CollectionType::class, array(
>             'entry_type' => SliderImageType::class,
>             'allow_add' => true,
>             'allow_delete' => true,
>             'label' => false,
>             'by_reference' => false
>         ))
> ```

but now, according to the symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html) you have to declare a field like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" })
 */
private $brochure;
```

So, like there is no relationship, how do i say i want multiple brochure for the current entity ( In my case i want to link multiple images to one project). And how to build my FormType? 
I'm sure it's trivial but i can't figure out

I tried with a one-to-one relationship and worked perfectly (profilePicture for a user)

Comment: You can use VichUploaderBundle. it's more easier and helpfull.

Comment: I think next time i will give a try to this bundle.